# changing css class and a jquery function when it reaches a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change a class from "class A" to "Class B" when it reaches DIV of "Class A" to "Class B"..

Here is the thing what I want, I have push menu when hamburger icon. The icon is generally in white background with black box shadow. My whole website background is dark. So it is perfect for dark background.

But I have few DIVs which are in white, when I reach that white DIV my menu is hardly visible.

So my question is I want to change the class of my menu from white to black when it reaches white background div. And I want to change the function of that menu as well in jquery. Because I have a "click" function to expand the menu.

Here is the HTML:

```js
$('.nav-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('.nav-menu').fadeToggle(200);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Advent Pro", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #23222a;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-trigger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-trigger span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 7px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.nav-trigger span:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger span:last-child {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger .on {
  top: 10px;
}

.nav-trigger.on span:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-trigger.on span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  transform: translateX(50px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-trigger.on span:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-trigger-dark {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-trigger-dark span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 7px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.nav-trigger-dark span:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger-dark span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger-dark span:last-child {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger-dark .on {
  top: 10px;
}

.nav-trigger-dark.on span:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-trigger-dark.on span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  transform: translateX(50px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-trigger-dark.on span:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 19;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
}
.nav-menu ul a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e65454;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a li {
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Advent Pro", sans-serif;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a li {
    top: 25%;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a h2.mb {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  /* 36/16 */
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mb {
    font-size: 1.688rem;
    /* 27/16 */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 61.9375em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mb {
    font-size: 2rem;
    /* 32/16 */
    margin-bottom: -13px;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a h2.mt {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  margin-bottom: -73px;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  /* 36/16 */
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mt {
    font-size: 1.688rem;
    /* 27/16 */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 61.9375em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mt {
    font-size: 2rem;
    /* 32/16 */
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a i {
  font-style: normal;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  /* 30/16 */
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a i {
    display: none;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #e65454;
}
.nav-menu ul a:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.nav-menu ul a:hover i {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.nav-menu ul a.active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #e65454;
}
.nav-menu ul a.active:hover {
  color: #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
.bgwhite {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-trigger">
   <span></span><span></span><span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
   <ul>
    <a href="#"> <li><h2 class="mt">Home</h2><i>Go to</i></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><h2 class="mb">About</h2><i>Me</i></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><h2 class="mt">Work</h2><i>My</i></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><h2 class="mb">Contact</h2><i>Me</i></li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
<section>
  <div class="content">
    
    </div>
  </section>
<section class="bgwhite">
  <div class="content">
    
    </div>
  </section>
```

as you can see in the snippit above when i reach the white background section, my hamburger menu trigger is hardly visible..

I have a css class with dark menu in the name of "nav-trigger dark".

Now I want to change that "nav-trigger" class to "nav-trigger-dark" class in that html and in that jquery script as well.

Comment: Add those css and div also or make a fiddle

Comment: @MostafaBaezid i added css too..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You have a series of menu items with a nav-trigger class, but in the case where the element's background is like instead you want it to have the nav-trigger-dark class? What is it that gives the div a white background in the first place?

Comment: @EmJiMadhu Add full html code please ..  [ http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/3xfrayp5/ ] with your code I dont get nothing

Comment: The is two closing curly braces missing in the CSS.. One on line #19 to close `.nav-trigger` and the other on line #45 to close `.nav-trigger-dark`. AND there is a lot of missing HTML. Can't see any `div` with "dark" or "white" background.

Comment: hi all sorry for the delay, i added full code snippit in the post, so that you guys will understand my question exactly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I understood the effect you're trying to achieve.

In my solution I listen to the `scroll` event on the document and when I reach a new section I check whether that section contains a particular class, if it does I alter my navbar class to match the style I want to display.

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/4qg9utk2/1/) for more information.

It goes like this:

HTML:

```
<nav>
 <p class="js_header white">
   Text
 </p>
</nav>

<section class="bg-black"></section>
<section class="bg-white"></section>
<section class="bg-black"></section>
<section class="bg-white"></section>
```

CSS (the important part):

```
nav .white { 
  color: white;
}

nav .black { 
  color: black;
}

section.bg-black {
  background-color: black;
}

section.bg-white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
  $.each($('section'), function (index, section) {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= section.getBoundingClientRect().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= section.getBoundingClientRect().bottom){
      if ($(section).hasClass('bg-black')) {
        $('.js_header').removeClass('black');      
        $('.js_header').addClass('white');      
      } else {
        $('.js_header').removeClass('white');      
        $('.js_header').addClass('black');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

**UPDATE:** Ok I got what you mean on your comments, in order to change the nav click behaviour when changing the class you need to add the listener to the body targeting the selector you want, instead of binding to the specific class from the beginning.

The JS would go like this for the changing the click behaviour:

```
$('body').on('click', '.nav-trigger', function() {
    alert('light clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('.nav-menu').fadeToggle(200);
});

$('body').on('click', '.nav-trigger-dark', function() {
    alert('dark clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('.nav-menu').fadeToggle(200);
});
```

I've altered your snippet to the following:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.nav-trigger', function() {
    alert('light clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('.nav-menu').fadeToggle(200);
});

$('body').on('click', '.nav-trigger-dark', function() {
    alert('dark clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('.nav-menu').fadeToggle(200);
});

$(document).scroll(function (e) {
      $.each($('section'), function (index, section) {
       if($(this).scrollTop() >= section.getBoundingClientRect().top && $(this).scrollTop() <= section.getBoundingClientRect().bottom){
      if ($(section).hasClass('bgwhite')) {
            $('.js_navbar').removeClass('nav-trigger');      
            $('.js_navbar').addClass('nav-trigger-dark');
          } else {
            $('.js_navbar').removeClass('nav-trigger-dark');      
            $('.js_navbar').addClass('nav-trigger');   
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Advent Pro", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #23222a;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-trigger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-trigger span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 7px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.nav-trigger span:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger span:last-child {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger .on {
  top: 10px;
}

.nav-trigger.on span:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-trigger.on span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  transform: translateX(50px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-trigger.on span:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-trigger-dark {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: top .1s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-trigger-dark span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 7px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.nav-trigger-dark span:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger-dark span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger-dark span:last-child {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-trigger-dark .on {
  top: 10px;
}

.nav-trigger-dark.on span:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-trigger-dark.on span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  transform: translateX(50px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-trigger-dark.on span:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 19;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
}
.nav-menu ul a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e65454;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a li {
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Advent Pro", sans-serif;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a li {
    top: 25%;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a h2.mb {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  /* 36/16 */
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mb {
    font-size: 1.688rem;
    /* 27/16 */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 61.9375em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mb {
    font-size: 2rem;
    /* 32/16 */
    margin-bottom: -13px;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a h2.mt {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  margin-bottom: -73px;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  /* 36/16 */
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mt {
    font-size: 1.688rem;
    /* 27/16 */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 61.9375em) {
  .nav-menu ul a h2.mt {
    font-size: 2rem;
    /* 32/16 */
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a i {
  font-style: normal;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  /* 30/16 */
}
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .nav-menu ul a i {
    display: none;
  }
}
.nav-menu ul a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #e65454;
}
.nav-menu ul a:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.nav-menu ul a:hover i {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.nav-menu ul a.active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #e65454;
}
.nav-menu ul a.active:hover {
  color: #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
.bgwhite {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-trigger js_navbar">
   <span></span><span></span><span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
   <ul>
    <a href="#"> <li><h2 class="mt">Home</h2><i>Go to</i></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><h2 class="mb">About</h2><i>Me</i></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><h2 class="mt">Work</h2><i>My</i></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><h2 class="mb">Contact</h2><i>Me</i></li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
<section>
  <div class="content">
    
    </div>
  </section>
<section class="bgwhite">
  <div class="content">
    
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: @EmJiMadhu Hi! Did my answer solved your problem? If not I'm happy to be of any assistance. If it did, please mark it a the correct answer for future reference.

Comment: i added my full snippit in the post to helping you guys whats my question is about..

Comment: @EmJiMadhu Hey! Thanks for that, did you get a chance to look at this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/4qg9utk2/1/) I included? It does pretty much what you want, if you scroll down the `Result` sections you'd see the text is white when the background is black and it changes to black once the background is white.

Comment: Yes, i did saw your fiddle.. it is good.. but as you can see your demo only works for static content like changing clors of text and header background.. that is okay for one part and second which i require is that i added a click funtion for the menu trigger.. so in default it is "nav-trigger" for click function and after changing navigation color, it should update in the function as well, like "nav-trigger-dark".. you answered 50% of question and all i need is to change click function as well.. but thanks a lot.. thank you so much..!

Comment: @EmJiMadhu Oh! Got it, you want to also change the click behavior when changing classes, I've updated my answer, see if it helps you now.

Comment: thank you soooo much.. that was perfect..! you are awesome..! thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the offset of white elements and then compare that with the scroll value. Then if you are on that divs, you change your css :

```js
$(function() {
 var oTop = $('#blueDiv').offset().top - $('#blueDiv').outerHeight()  ;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    
   var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
     //console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop );
   if( pTop > oTop && pTop<oTop + $('#blueDiv').outerHeight() + $('#navbar').outerHeight()  ){
       white();
   }else {
     blue();
    }
 });
});

function white(){
 document.getElementById("navbar").className = "";
  document.getElementById("navbar").className = "navbar-white";
    //Add your code here
}

function blue(){
 document.getElementById("navbar").className = "";
  document.getElementById("navbar").className = "navbar-blue";
    //Add your code here
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  position : fixed;
  top : 0px;
  height : 30px;
  width:100%;
  opacity:0.7;
  }
  #blueDiv {
    background-color : blue;
    height:30px;
  }
  .navbar-white {
  background-color: white;
  }
  
  .navbar-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-blue">
menu
</div>
<p>&nbsp;s</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;s2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;s3</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;s4</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="blueDiv">counter...</div>

<p>&nbsp;s</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;s2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;s3</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;s4</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: i added my full snippit in the post to helping you guys whats my question is about.